# clang Error adding Pods to existing Cocos3D project

Tags: ios, cocos3d

I'm getting the following error after added pods to existing Cocos3D helloWorld project:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here are the steps performed:

1. Copy `CC3HelloWorld` project from the distribution into location /someplace/CC3HelloWorld/
2. Added the `SWTableViewCell` to Podfile
3. Via command line: pod install
4. Getting the following complaints:

> [!] The `CC3HelloWorld [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_CFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The `CC3HelloWorld [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The `CC3HelloWorld [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_CFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The `CC3HelloWorld [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>   Phams-MacBook-Pro:CC3HelloWorld phamdacloc$ pod install

5. I then went into Build Settings and added `$(inherited)` flag for `OTHER_CFLAGS` and `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.
6. Compiled and received the following error:

> ```
> ld: library not found for -lPods-SWTableViewCell
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

I can't seem to get pass this clang error. Note that this only happen when I copy the existing CC3HelloWorld project as a starting template to begin my work. The pods are working fine if I begin a brand new project not using Cocos3D. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Try by deleting the podfile from your project and reinstall by using following commands,

  If you are creating workspace of your project,
   Terminal-->cd Drag and drop your project(mention your project path)-->touch podfile-->open podfile(mention your podname)-->pod install (or) pod update
 Still you are facing the same issue check whether SWTableViewCell file is present in your pod.
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm still facing the same issue. I've removed CC3HelloWorld-iOS.workspace, Podfile.lock files and /Pods/ directory then performed pod install/pod update but no luck. SWTableViewCell is present in my /Pods/ directory.  I've added a screenshot of the failure I'm getting to my question above. Thanks.

Comment: After deleting the podfile, have you check with removing Check pods Manifest.lock and Copy Pods Resources from Build Phases??, Otherwise check with deleting test file under your target.